# How to change your samskaras?

Tags: vedas, shiva, mantras, yoga, shakti

I want to know if is there any method to change samsara since samsara has been given so much importance in our culture and scriptures is there any way to get rid of bad samskaras and create good ones

Comment: I think you’re on the right track. In the pranayam post you said you’re reading book about Aghori ? Maybe keep reading more and more stuff, online and books, internet archive, etc. Anything you’re interested in, search it on here in old topics, google extensively, go down every rabbit hole, ya know ? I think the more you just keep learning abt Hinduism by what interests you, the samskar will gradually change themselves to more religious type. You can research, experiment, try different techniques. Maybe try see it like a fun adventure you’re privileged to have, that’s kinda how I see it :D

Comment: Thnks you're a shakta right, is there any mantra for naam japa in shakta tradition which doesn't need initiation like on namha shivaya or om namo bhagvate vasudevaye

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the *Yoga Sūtras* explains this:

> **1.18. There is another samadhi which is attained by the constant practise of cessation of all mental activity, in which the mind retains only the unmanifested impressions (samskaras).**

By stilling the mind's activity, yoga or samādhi, all active samskaras, generating the mind's restless activity, are stopped. Then, we observe only that which has not yet surfaced, on account of the mind being clear.

> **1.50. The resulting impression from this samādhi  obstructs all other impressions.**

Abiding in yoga, no other samskaras can be created, because the mind is under control so all of its tendencies are restrained and it does not wander out towards any objects.

> **3.9. By the suppression of the disturbed modifications of the mind, and by the rise of modifications of control, the mind is said to attain the controlling modifications — following the controlling powers of the mind.**

Abiding in yoga, preventing any new samskaras and observing that which has not yet surfaced, one has the ability to orient the mind towards knowledge and away from ignorance. Thus, any new samskaras which are created are rooted in knowledge instead of ignorance. These samskaras counteract those which generate restlessness in the mind. In other words, that activity generated by knowledge obstructs ignorance; knowledge stops ignorance.

Ignorance is defined as,

> **2.5. taking that which is non-eternal, impure, painful and non-Self, for the eternal, pure, happy, Self.**

Non-Self - activity, that which is changeable. Self - that which is unchangeable and still. Abiding in the Self is stillness and yoga. Not achieving yoga is to identify with the mind's activity (non-Self).

With knowledge established in the mind, the mind can be controlled and yoga can be achieved more easily. Initially, it has to be achieved through stilling the mind's activity. But, when this has been achieved, when the mind is not still, because knowledge has a stronghold, the mind is oriented towards yoga. So, achieving yoga enables and is generated by the mind being oriented towards knowledge.

> **4.25. Then, bent on discriminating, the mind attains the previous state of Kaivalya.**
>
> **4.26. The thoughts that arise as obstructions to that are from impressions.**

Here it says how to create good samskaras - cultivate discrimination, the ability to tell knowledge from ignorance, Self from non-Self. By stilling the mind's activity, one can discern easily. This is why, outside of yoga, one cannot discern and why stilling the mind is necessary. With a restless mind, one cannot see clearly and confuses ignorance with knowledge, on account of the mind's clarity being obscured by the activity which takes place within it.

Identify which thoughts are rooted in ignorance and which in knowledge. In other words, which thoughts are true and which are not. We should not hold onto those which are false, which keeps us in samsara.